# Config .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, hosting

It's my first time deploying a web app on a hosting and they give me this .htaccess but i've never configured one, i have a root directory then a public_html and at the same level my webpage. i'll show you the directory tree and the content of the .htaccess

```
root
|
|---project
|---public_html
|---.htaccess
```

The content of the .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And when I enter the website it's showing me a http 403 error: Server or website configuration is blocking you from viewing this page.

I have never configured a website on a hosting so I don't know what i'm doing most of the time...

Thx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> root
> |
> |---project
> |---public_html
> |---.htaccess
> ```

Assuming `public_html` is the *document root* (where your public facing files and `index.php` are located) then the `.htaccess` file should be in the `public_html` directory itself (not above it).

That is...

```
root
|
|---project
|---public_html
|------.htaccess
```

By placing the `.htaccess` file in the `root` directory (above the document root) then it would attempt to rewrite the request to `/root/index.php` (as opposed to `/root/public_html/index.php`) which is inaccessible (from rewriting in `.htaccess`) and does not exist anyway, so would likely result in a 403, 400, etc.